# how can i filter my dataframe?

Tags: r, parsing

I have a df that have several columns (see below)

```
 V1    V2       V3         V4             V5 V6   V7       V8       V9    V10  V11 V12
 A01 10378809 10379882 Contig1401|m.3412 101 -  10378809 10379882 255,0,0  1 1073   0
 A01 10469105 10469293 Contig1755|m.4465  48  + 10469105 10469293 255,0,0  2  188   0
 A01 10469429 10469630 Contig1755|m.4465   5  + 10469429 10469630 255,0,0  NA  201  0
```

How can i do something like this?

```
A01 10378809 10379882 Contig1401|m.3412 101 -  10378809 10379882 255,0,0  1 1073   0    
A01 10469105 10469293 Contig1755|m.4465  48  + 10469105 10469293 255,0,0   2  188,201 0
```

Basically if it is a unique id (for example `Contig1401|m.3412`) then don't do anything. And if the id is non-unique (i.e shared with either next line or next line after and so on... for example `Contig1755|m.4465`) then paste the value of v11 to the preceding line? I tried a lot but couldn't find a way. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: And rest of the values can be dropped?

Comment: Yes. They can be dropped.

Comment: Check out `?duplicated`, in particular the `fromLast` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in one column, you can do following:

```
df <- data.frame(x=sample(letters, size=50, replace=T), y=sample(50))

aggregate(df$y, by=list(df$x), FUN=paste)
   Group.1              x
1        a      41, 6, 15
2        b      39, 37, 5
3        c         48, 50
4        e         20, 26
5        f          25, 2
6        g              1
7        h             29
8        i         31, 44
9        j             43
10       k 33, 45, 19, 46
11       l         11, 28
12       o             38
13       p      42, 8, 32
14       q          3, 21
15       r  47, 4, 34, 24
16       s              7
17       t     18, 17, 35
18       u     23, 13, 27
19       w             16
20       x     12, 36, 10
21       y     30, 22, 14
22       z      9, 49, 40
```

In your case, replace `df$x` with `df$V1` and `df$y` with `df$V11`

Answer (score 0):

How about this with `dplyr`. Note, this uses the first value of each non-aggregating variable (i.e. not V4 or V11), and it rolls up V11 per V4:

```
df<-read.table(header=T,text="V1    V2       V3         V4             V5 V6   V7       V8       V9    V10  V11 V12
 A01 10378809 10379882 Contig1401|m.3412 101 -  10378809 10379882 255,0,0  1 1073   0
 A01 10469105 10469293 Contig1755|m.4465  48  + 10469105 10469293 255,0,0  2  188   0
 A01 10469429 10469630 Contig1755|m.4465   5  + 10469429 10469630 255,0,0  NA  201  0")

require(dplyr)

df.2<-group_by(df, V4) %.%
  summarise(V1=V1[1],V2=V2[1],V3=V3[1],V5=V5[1],V6=V6[1],V7=V7[1],
  V8=V8[1],V9=V9[1],V10=V10[1],V11=paste0(unlist(V11),collapse=","),V12=V12[1])

data.frame(df.2)

                 V4 V1       V2       V3  V5 V6       V7       V8 V9 V10
1 Contig1401|m.3412  1 10378809 10379882 101  1 10378809 10379882  1   1
2 Contig1755|m.4465  1 10469105 10469293  48  2 10469105 10469293  1   2
V11 V12
1    1073   0
2 188,201   0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never know that dplyr exists. I knew a little bit about plyr but not dplyr. Anyway it worked. However when i tried to manipulate to add some more calculations, i ran into trouble. Here is what i am trying to do.... `df.2.t<-group_by(df, V4) %.%
  summarise(V1=V1[1],V2=V2[1],V3=V3[2],V5=V5[1],V6=V6[1],V7=V7[1],
            V8=V8[1],V9=V9[1],V10=V10[1],V11=paste0(unlist(V11),collapse=","),V12=paste0(unlist((V2[2])-(V2[1])),collapse=",")

data.frame(df.2)`. Where am i doing wrong you think?

Comment: I have figured out of how to do some calculations. However i have still some pending issues `as.data.frame(df %.% group_by(V4) %.% summarise(V1= V1[1], V12=paste(0,max(V2)-min(V2),sep=","), V2=min(V2), V3=max(V3), V5=V5[1], V6=V6[1], V7=min(V7), V8=max(V8), V9=V9[1], V10=V10[1],V11=paste0(unlist(V11),collapse=",")))`. Firstly for calculating my V12 column i trying to subtract the min from the max values but when there are more than 3 ids in a group iam only getting 2 with this approach. Also for 12th column for the non group i am getting this `0,0` values whereas i want only 0. Thanks